# Swiffy conflict with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, google-swiffy

I converted flash animation to swiffy. When I try to embed it on my website it doesn't work. I have also prototype loaded. Without prototype it works. With prototype there is an error:

Chrome:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

There is some kind of infinite recursion.

Do you have anny idea how to fix it, or maybe there is a fixed version of swiffy runtime library somewhere?

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/wbs938b9/

```
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
      swiffyobject, {  });
stage.start();
```

Comment: Having a similar problem. Just embedding the Swiffy runtime.js throws an error.  I get "TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "day" in runtime.js.  Looks like the runtime doesn't play nice with other scripts.